# Using RACADM via SSL to get hardware fault information

Tags: drac

I have several Dell R815 servers I'm trying to get hardware fault information from.  My remote server is a Linux box running RHEL6.  I have downloaded and installed the racadm software and can run it as root.  I have a service account set up which I have added to the Dell server and also have uploaded the SSL key for the service account.

Here is what I want to be able to do:

1. Run a script via cron from the service account (done)
2. The script will run a racadm command against the Dell server without needing a password
3. The data I need from the server is any hardware faults that currently exist

This is all simple on a Sun/Oracle server using a single ilom command.  I'm getting the idea that it's not so simple on Dell servers.

I've been searching for this information all day and have tried reading the iDRAC6 User Guide but I have yet to find the answers I seek.

Thanks for any guidance you can throw my way.

Answer (score 0):

My tool of choice for this is Dell OpenManage Server Administrator and specifically the [check_openmanage](http://folk.uio.no/trondham/software/check_openmanage.html) Nagios plugin.  `check_openmanage` works as a standalone program so you don't have to use it in conjunction with Nagios; you can just run it from a script, capture its output, and examine its exit code to see if there are any problems on your system.

To install OMSA, you need to add the [Dell OpenManage repository](http://linux.dell.com/wiki/index.php/Repository/OMSA), install the `srvadmin-all` package, and start the `dataeng` service.  Once that's in place, just download, unpack, and run check_openmanage.